# Solve system of equations $9^y=3^x$ and $2\log_2{x}-\log_43=\log_2y$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve system of equations $9^y=3^x$ and $2\log_2{x}-\log_43=\log_2y$.
I got $2y=x$ and $2\log_2{x} - \frac{1}{2}\log3=\log_2\frac{1}{2}x$. I am stuck at this point. Could you provide a hint ?

Comment: First use the formula $a\log_2(b)=\log_2(b^a)$ to each term on the left-hand side. Then use the formula $\log_2(c)-\log_2(d)=\log_2(c/d)$ to combine the terms on the left-hand side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Rewrite $$2\log_{2}x-\frac{1}{2}\log_{2}3\rightarrow\log_{2}x^2-\log_{2}3^{1/2}=\log_{2}\frac{x^{2}}{3^{1/2}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Remember that by definition, $\log_43$ is the real number, say $z,$ such that $4^z=3.$ Put another way, $(2^2)^z=3.$ Put yet another way, $2^{2\cdot z}=3.$ Translated back into terms of logarithms, $$2z=\log_23,$$ so that $$\log_43=z=\frac12\log_23.$$

This may have been what you've done already, though your post doesn't actually show it (there's an index missing). If that *is* what you've done, then your second equation should actually show $$2\log_2x-\frac12\log_2 3=\log_2y,$$ or equivalently, $$4\log_2x-\log_23=2\log_2y.$$ This is again equivalent to $$4\log_2x=2\log_2y+\log_23,$$ or $$\log_2x^4=\log_2y^2+\log_23,$$ or $$\log_2x^4=\log_23y^2,$$ or finally $$x^4=3y^2.$$ Since $x=2y,$ and since $x$ and $y$ are both positive (*do you see why?*) what can we conclude?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$\boxed{2\log_2x - \log_2\left(\frac x2 \right)}= \log_2(x^2) - \log_2\left(\frac x2\right) = \log_2\left(\frac{x^2}{x/2}\right) = \boxed{\log_2(2x) }$

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there.

We have
$$2\log_2{x} - \frac{1}{2}\log_23=\log_2\frac{1}{2}x\\
2\log_2x-\frac12\log_23=\log_2x-1\\
\log_2x=\frac12\log_23-1\\
x=\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\\
y=\frac{\sqrt3}4
$$